# ASP.net or jQuery modal pop-up solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a modal pop-up solution with the following requirements:

1.) Usable with ASP.net.
2.) The modal pop-up's height is dynamic, for example: the modal pop-up's height would grow based on how much content was in it and if your content is going to make the pop-up taller than the browser's available height, the content would be scrollable.

Currently, we are using the ASP.net modal pop-up extender and if our pop-up is larger than the browser window, you have to click and drag. This becomes a problem when the user has a very small resolution and the modal pop-up's drag handle is obscured by the browser's toolbars.

I was just wondering if anyone else has run into this problem, if so, how did they solve it.

Thank you in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JQuery dialogs?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal